# How to precisely set breakpoint when debugging remotely using PDB

Tags: django, pdb

I want to set breakpoint in `like()` function in below source code,

```
## views.py

@csrf_protect
@login_required
def like(request, comment_id, next=None):
```

However, in PDB prompt, when I use command `break views.like` to set break,
the breakpoint goes to `Breakpoint 1 at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py:119`, then after so many subsequent `continue` and `next` commands expecting to step into `like()` function soon, i failed and got lost.

is there a way to set breakpoint and skip all those decorators ? or any convenient ways for me to view source file (views.py) remotely under PDB command prompt to identify which line to set breakpoint ?

Comment: You can temporarily add to the implementation of your method `like()` the following line of code: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`. The breakpoint then starts at that line.

Comment: but under `pdb` prompt, I have no access to any file command such as `vi` or `vim`, I have to exit `pdb` and use `vim` to achieve this. I am looking for a convenient way which does not require me to exit `pdb`.

Comment: Good point. I am not a pdb expert, so unfortunately I cannot help you further. :-(

Comment: Can you not set up multiple ssh connections to the server, and do pdb in one session and vi/vim in another? Or you could use gnu screen https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/ and switch between sessions.